# Is it possible/safe to assign back to the same variable when using dictionary comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following statement:

```
catalog = {k: v for k, v in catalog.items() if predicate(v)}
```

which is using the very same variable left side what is referenced in the dictionary comprehension in right side.

(I do not know what of the comprehension execution is doing in place, what are the iterator(s) yielding and if there are some lazy eval behind the scenes, so having wild fantasy I can imagine that the dictionary is corrupting because some iteration is modifying the subject of iteration.)

**Question**

Is the statement above is guaranteed to be safe for some reason, or just avoid for it?

Comment: It's safe.  The assignment can't actually take place until the right-hand side has been fully evaluated.